# Typescript Reference Issue

Tags: typescript, reference

So I have a web application that does some basic analytics on some user imported data. It lets the user map columns, and we show the properties on a map, show different statistics on the properties, etc.

We are adding a feature that is dependent on the particular mapped column, and when I am going through it, I can't understand the output and why I would have an issue. The relevant function is below. I pass a list of objects to it and remove the data associated to the unified field. SO mapping. Guess might be 'Address,' and mapping.field might be 'Street Address' in the CSV for example.

```
deleteMapping(field: string, data?: Array<any>, render?: boolean)
{
    if (!field || typeof field !== 'string')
        throw { message: "delete mapping expects a string parameter"}

    var mapping = this.mapping[field];

    if (!mapping)
        return;

    this.mapping[field] = null;
    this.inverseMapping[mapping.guess] = null;

    if (Array.isArray(data))
    {
        console.log(mapping.guess);
        console.log(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            console.log(data[i][mapping.guess]);
            data[i][mapping.guess] = null;
            console.log(data[i][mapping.guess]);
        }
        console.log(data);

        try
        {
            $("body").trigger("analytics:unbind",{ field: mapping.field, unified: mapping.guess, render: render === undefined ? true : render}); 
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            console.error(e);
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is that the console. Logs aren't making any sense to me.

1. mapping.guess = 'Address' as expected
2. data = My Initial Array as expected
3. First data[i][mapping.guess] = the Address of the individual property as expected
4. Second data[i][mapping.guess] = null as expected
5. data = My Initial Array *UNCHANGED*

I don't understand why the array item isn't having its value checked. Any ideas. I also don't know how data[i][mapping.guess] in the array returns correctly in the loop. Ultimately at a loss, as I'm setting the value to null, then it returns null. Why wouldn't the value in the array be null after the loop?

Edit: ... think i figured it out. Think the console.log is a bit asynchronous. The address gets rebuilt in the following 'unbind' event and when it prints it is reconstructed from other data. Didn't realize console.log might defer its results.

Answer (score 0):

Tricky, at least without full code.

For debug accuracy with console.log, change your all console.log calls to console.log(JSON.stringify... ex:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data,null,2)); // dont work with auto referencied objects
```

Without full code, its hard to know. You can try setting to undefined or creating a new object

```
data[i][mapping.guess] = {};
```

Comment: It's cool, i figured it out. console.log doesn't appear to write immediately on arrays or objects (not 100% sure) or does them asynchronously.  I didn't know it did that, but it explains the odd response as a function called after the console.log added the values  back to the array.